# Using Stack Navigation with Drawer Navigation always ends up in home page

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

First of, sorry about the title. I did't know how else to explain what I am going for. I have a Drawer Navigation with a Stack Navigation inside of it. The reason why I did this is because I wanted a `SinglePage` and `CommentPage` which will be unmounted when left. And my main Navigation is the Drawer Navigation. The problem for me is that If I go in to one of the screens inside of the drawer navigation and from there, go in to the `SinglePage` (by tapping on an article), and now if I go back, it goes all the way back to home and not the previous page which is the other drawer navigation page.

I have already tried changing the order of my Routes but that did not help. Here is the Code I am working with:

```
//This is my Routes file which is located in my project root folder
//Here is the Stack Navigator

const SinglePageNavigator = createStackNavigator({

    Home: { screen: Home },
    SinglePage: { screen: SinglePage },
    CommentPage: { screen: Comments },

},

{
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    mode: "card",
    headerMode: "none",
}
);


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    drawerLabelStyle: {
        fontFamily: 'MV_Waheed',
        fontWeight: '200',
        fontSize: 16,
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'flex-end'
    }
});

//And here is my Drawer Navigation. I have removed some screens

  const TopLevelNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({

    Home: {screen: SinglePageNavigator, navigationOptions: {
    title: 'Home',
    }},

    Catpage: {screen: CatPage, navigationOptions: {title: 'News'}, params: {catID:1000, thisRouteName: 'News'}},

    Catpage: {screen: CatPage, navigationOptions: {title: 'Entertainment'}, params: {catID:1000, thisRouteName: 'Entertainment'}},

},

{
    hideStatusBar: false,
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    drawerPosition: 'right',
    drawerBackgroundColor: '#2a292d',
    overlayColor: '#2a292d',
    contentOptions: {
        activeTintColor: '#fff',
        inactiveTintColor:'#fff' ,
        activeBackgroundColor: '#ff4136',
        labelStyle: styles.drawerLabelStyle,
    },
},

  );

  const AppContainer = createAppContainer(TopLevelNavigator);
```

So as shown, my Drawer navigation except for Home page takes in one page called CatsPage which then takes in a param and depending on that, it makes an API call and fetches data. Now Inside that, I have a button which goes to single page viewing the data of that article. Every time I go back, the singlepage gets unmounted. It works as intended. But the problem here is that if I am in page Entertainment and open an article from inside of there and go back, it goes back to home and not Entertainment. I can not wrap my head around of why that is. I did remove the `initialRouteName: Home` from Stack navigator thinking that might have been the issue but that did not help either. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using the `same page` at the same time is not a good idea. It may not work as intended. And the same thing about `routename` is not good either.

You can try with '`createStackNavigator`'

```js
const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({

    Drawers: { screen: TopLevelNavigator }

});
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
```

Comment: Wait so do you mean I should keep my other StackNavigator and put this in? Or should I replace it with this?

Comment: Yes, keep the old one and put in the new stack.

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand what you mean by "Using the same page at the same time is not a good idea. It may not work as intended. And the same thing about routename is not good either."

Comment: This is what is happening. With or without your suggested Code. I am attaching a gif. The problem is that if I go to drawer, then click something other than home and open an article from there, then press back, it goes to home. It should go back to my category which I selected from drawer right? Here is a gif: https://ibb.co/bFTr24t

Comment: 'RouteName' means not to use the same name and not to overlap the screen.

Comment: I am not using the same route name

Comment: Yes but that is screen name right? Not route name. I have one file which acts as a screen. That file has a function which accepts a param which i am passing from the routes. CatID param is passed. And it calls api to show data. It doesn’t overlap. So how can I use cateogry page? Do I have to create multiple category pages and replace the screen? Thats not very convenient. And that makes the project static. If i want to add another page in future, i have to create another file? Also your suggested code doesn’t work. Still same problem

Comment: See this for instructions on how you can transfer data to a page. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html

Comment: Ok! Sir. I appreciate your answer. But this is not helping. I already have GOOD WORKING routes and I can pass parameters with no problems. My problem is not that. Take a look at my previous comment. https://ibb.co/bFTr24t this is my problem. I go to drawer and select an option from there. And in that option there are many articles. I open an article. And when I go back, it goes back to home page and not the other drawer page I had open previously. It is not a problem with route name or screen name or passing parameter. I already tested, I don't know what the problem is. That is why i am here!

Comment: Now all your backs are moving home.

Comment: Your category is the same file now. It is impossible to move from the same file to the same file unless it is updated. Moving from home to home is possible because it is a page composed of different files, not the same file.

Comment: This is a matter of stacks. Something seems wrong with the structure.

Comment: Ok but what? I can’t figureout what it is

Comment: Can you provide a simple example of this problem?

Comment: I already have!! The link I provided you shows whats wrong. I pasted it twice in 2 comments. And the route file is as exactly how it is in my project. I can’t give you my project files

Comment: I didn't mean to ask for the project file, but asked if you could give me an example code to reproduce your problem equally.

Comment: Here is a test project I replicated the issue with. Please download from the link. I am on another machine and I do not want to go through git so Here is a zip: https://gofile.io/?c=xtY393 let me know if you need anything else

Comment: Node modules is not added

Comment: All of your screens are moving to the same screen. That's why I have no choice but to move home.